# How to eject a drive automatically after pen drive is plugged in?

Tags: macos, usb

I have set up a .plist file which would automatically backup my files whenever I plug in my pen drive but I would like to eject it after the process is complete. How do I accomplish this?

Here is my job definition - how do I modify it to eject my drive after backup is complete:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd >
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.company.popup</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>sh</string>
        <string>-c</string>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/backup</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartOnMount</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

PS. I have put thus file under ~/Library/LaunchAgents

Comment: You need to eject it in the shell script, not the launchd plist. `man diskutil` might help

Comment: Also: Please have a look at the edit I've made to see how formatting works  here.

Answer (score 1):

You just have change the UNIX executable file.Modify it like  `rsync -aH source destination && diskutil eject /Volumes/BACKUP >> desktop/log.txt`

Comment: If `rsync` fails then `Volumes/BACKUP` will not be ejected. Is this your desired result?

Comment: No rsync does not fail it works perfectly fine.And how can rsync fail please do give an example.

Comment: @geek there are a lot of reasons rsync can fail, eg. permission errors on read or write. With your current code you have no way of finding out whether something went wrong

Comment: Yes you are right @Patrix but I have found a way to save the output of the file to a .txt by adding `>> log.txt` to the end of the shell script.Thanks by the way for warning.